# if open () creates a stream object in python why is it referred to as a function instead of a class

Tags: python, function, class, object, python-3.7

I am still learning the ropes with python, but wanted to clarify an observation.

Consider the statement below

```
stream = open ("C:\text.txt", "rt")
```

if open (arg1, arg2) creates a stream object denoted as 'stream' above , why is open () considered a function instead of a class?, after all this is how an object is instantiated from a class.

Comment: Notice that `open()` does *not* return an object of type `open`.  Just because the syntax is the same doesn't mean it's doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can return an instance of a class. The class will defined outside the function, and the function will initialize the class using its arguments and return the initialized class instance. `open()` can also work this way.